# Connection refused error in mysql jdbc for android

Tags: java, android, mysql

I want to access mysql db in android studio through jdbc connection.I have written the code for jdbc connection.

I am getting error on line:-

```
 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "myLogin", "myPassword");
```

And getting the following output:-

```
03-18 13:53:49.663  10650-10944/com.example.lenovo.beacon W/System.err? com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception:
03-18 13:53:49.663  10650-10944/com.example.lenovo.beacon W/System.err? [ 03-18 13:53:49.663 10650:10944 W/System.err ]
    ** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **
03-18 13:53:49.663  10650-10944/com.example.lenovo.beacon W/System.err? [ 03-18 13:53:49.663 10650:10944 W/System.err ]
    java.net.ConnectException
03-18 13:53:49.663  10650-10944/com.example.lenovo.beacon W/System.err? MESSAGE: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 3306): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
03-18 13:53:49.663  10650-10944/com.example.lenovo.beacon W/System.err? [ 03-18 13:53:49.663 10650:10944 W/System.err ]
    STACKTRACE:
03-18 13:53:49.663  10650-10944/com.example.lenovo.beacon W/System.err? [ 03-18 13:53:49.663 10650:10944 W/System.err ]
    java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 3306): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
03-18 13:53:49.663  10650-10944/com.example.lenovo.beacon W/System.err? at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:124)
03-18 13:53:49.663  10650-10944/com.example.lenovo.beacon W/System.err? at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
03-18 13:53:49.663  10650-10944/com.example.lenovo.beacon W/System.err? at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:163)
03-18 13:53:49.663  10650-10944/com.example.lenovo.beacon W/System.err? at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:590)
03-18 13:53:49.663  10650-10944/com.example.lenovo.beacon W/System.err? at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:226)
03-18 13:53:49.663  10650-10944/com.example.lenovo.beacon W/System.err? at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256)
03-18 13:53:49.663  10650-10944/com.example.lenovo.beacon W/System.err? at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:271)
03-18 13:53:49.663  10650-10944/com.example.lenovo.beacon W/System.err? at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2771)
03-18 13:53:49.663  10650-10944/com.example.lenovo.beacon W/System.err? at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
03-18 13:53:49.663  10650-10944/com.example.lenovo.beacon W/System.err? at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
03-18 13:53:49.663  10650-10944/com.example.lenovo.beacon W/System.err? at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:179)
03-18 13:53:49.663  10650-10944/com.example.lenovo.beacon W/System.err? at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:213)
03-18 13:53:49.663  10650-10944/com.example.lenovo.beacon W/System.err? at com.example.lenovo.beacon.MainActivity$2.insert(MainActivity.java:110)
03-18 13:53:49.663  10650-10944/com.example.lenovo.beacon W/System.err? at com.example.lenovo.beacon.MainActivity$2$1.run(MainActivity.java:98)
03-18 13:53:49.663  10650-10944/com.example.lenovo.beacon W/System.err? at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
03-18 13:53:49.663  10650-10944/com.example.lenovo.beacon W/System.err? Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
03-18 13:53:49.663  10650-10944/com.example.lenovo.beacon W/System.err? at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
03-18 13:53:49.663  10650-10944/com.example.lenovo.beacon W/System.err? at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:111)
03-18 13:53:49.663  10650-10944/com.example.lenovo.beacon W/System.err? at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:137)
03-18 13:53:49.663  10650-10944/com.example.lenovo.beacon W/System.err? at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
03-18 13:53:49.663  10650-10944/com.example.lenovo.beacon W/System.err? ... 14 more
03-18 13:53:49.663  10650-10944/com.example.lenovo.beacon W/System.err? [ 03-18 13:53:49.663 10650:10944 W/System.err ]
03-18 13:53:49.663  10650-10944/com.example.lenovo.beacon W/System.err? ** END NESTED EXCEPTION **
03-18 13:53:49.663  10650-10944/com.example.lenovo.beacon W/System.err? [ 03-18 13:53:49.663 10650:10944 W/System.err ]
03-18 13:53:49.663  10650-10944/com.example.lenovo.beacon W/System.err? [ 03-18 13:53:49.663 10650:10944 W/System.err ]
    Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
03-18 13:53:49.663  10650-10944/com.example.lenovo.beacon W/System.err? at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2847)
03-18 13:53:49.663  10650-10944/com.example.lenovo.beacon W/System.err? at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
03-18 13:53:49.663  10650-10944/com.example.lenovo.beacon W/System.err? at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
03-18 13:53:49.663  10650-10944/com.example.lenovo.beacon W/System.err? at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:179)
03-18 13:53:49.663  10650-10944/com.example.lenovo.beacon W/System.err? at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:213)
03-18 13:53:49.663  10650-10944/com.example.lenovo.beacon W/System.err? at com.example.lenovo.beacon.MainActivity$2.insert(MainActivity.java:110)
03-18 13:53:49.663  10650-10944/com.example.lenovo.beacon W/System.err? at com.example.lenovo.beacon.MainActivity$2$1.run(MainActivity.java:98)
03-18 13:53:49.663  10650-10944/com.example.lenovo.beacon W/System.err? at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Please suggest me the mistake

Comment: You are trying to connect to a mysql database on 127.0.0.1 - are you running mysql server on the android device?

Comment: on Android you have to use this 10.0.2.2:portnumber instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: I m not running mysql server on android device

Comment: I have refered this link :- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X9bboz-z_1s